# Several uploads to servlet in one request

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, file-upload

In Servlet 3.1 it is possible to upload multiple files to servlet in one request (like a bulk upload), but what I want to achieve is to upload a big number of files to servlet as soon as each one is created without creating a new request on every file. In other words, there are 1000 files created on runtime, and I do not want 1st one to wait for the creation of the last to be uploaded. I want each file uploaded immediately after creation, so that servlet can check the upload timestamp for each file (and send back the result). The hard part for me is, I want neither to wait for creating all of them, nor to use separate requests for each file.

Is that possible? If yes, please give me some tips and directions/sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible read multiple files in a single servlet request.

Here is how you could read the files in the servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/UploadServlet" })
@MultipartConfig(location = "/uploads")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
                String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
                out.println("... writing " + fileName");
                part.write(fileName);
                out.println("... uploaded to: /uploads/" + fileName);
            }

    }
}
```

**Update:**
Based on your updated question, you have ~1000 files that you want to "stream" to the server as they are created.  It's not possible to add more parts to an existing post request, and I think it would be a bit excessive to try and upload all 1000 files in a single POST request anyway.

I recommend setting some arbitrary chunk size (say 20 files at a time for example) and batch them up and make a POST requests for every 20 files.  This way, you are not waiting for all 1000 files to be created, and you are not doing everything over a single POST request.  This will allow you to "stream" your files to the server in 20 file increments.

Comment: I know the servlet can read many files via request.getparts(), but my question is, should all these files be sent altogether or can they be sent once they are created, one by one? I am more interested in client side code

Comment: ok... I'm confused at what your question is now.  You said "in servlet 3.1 is it possible", but you are talking about client side?  Also, why do you want to send files one-by-one now?  Your original question said "upload multiple files in one request".  Please clarify your question

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry if I was not clear enough. My goal is to check statistics for each created file (the timestamp when each one reached the server), but I do not know if this is possible in one request

Comment: Streaming is exactly what I intended. I am very grateful for the servlet snippet you posted.  Could you also give me some source/links that describe client side as well - programatically streaming 1000 files to servlet (but without JSP/JSF, HTML)? The whole point is that it should be one request (this is a strict requirement for current testing purposes). Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  If you really want to do all 1000 in a single POST in a java test environment, check out the following link for example usage of Apache's `HttpClient` https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/servlet/file-upload/src

Comment: this is what I was looking for. great example.